# Does a script always execute the full length of a loop when it encounters one, before continuing with statements after it?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var flag = false;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 10) {
    flag = true;
    console.log(`Flag is ${flag}`);
    break;
  }
}
if (!flag) {
  console.log(`Flag is still ${flag}`);
}
```

So as a person new to programming, I am wondering - is there ANY possibility of the script, as it is, to execute the condition outside the loop, BEFORE the loop has finished iterating ?

Comment: No. What's the use case? Why would moving the `if` statement inside the loop not work?

Comment: _"as it is"_ - No. But the actual question is: why the loop at all? `if (i === 10)` won't ever be true.

Comment: Except for asynchronous functions, everything in a script executes in order.

Comment: This is true in almost all programming languages. You have to take explicit actions to cause things to execute out of order.

Comment: Yes, the condition inside the loop would never be true, i get that :)
It was just used for demonstration purposes. The loop will iterate 10 times regardless, but what I wasn't sure about was if the condition after it is going to wait for the loop to finish, before executing.
Apparently - "Except for asynchronous functions, everything in a script executes in order.", so that's that. Thank you!